# valgrind shows an error when running a comparison

Tags: c, valgrind

I have the following function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "block.h"

bool block_equal(const struct block *block1, const struct block *block2) {
    if ((block1 == NULL) ^ (block2 == NULL))
        return false;
    else if (block1 == NULL & block2 == NULL)
        return true;
    else {
        // ... Some stuff
    }
}
```

When I run it with a pointer to an initialized `struct block` and `NULL`, valgrind shows this error (line 6 is the first comparison):

```
==24444== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24444==    at 0x402E34: block_equal (block.c:6)
==24444==    by 0x4025D3: test_chunks_write (test_chunks.c:22)
==24444==    by 0x4E31FE8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcunit.so.1.0.1)
==24444==    by 0x4E323C6: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcunit.so.1.0.1)
==24444==    by 0x4E326E7: CU_run_all_tests (in /usr/lib/libcunit.so.1.0.1)
==24444==    by 0x401627: main (tests.c:15)
```

EDIT: Here is the call of `block_equal`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>
#include "../chunks.h"
#include "../block.h"

void test_chunks_write(void) {
    struct block *block1, *block2;
    block1 = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    block2 = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    block1->type = BLOCK_WOOD;
    block2->type = BLOCK_STONE;
    chunks *chunks = chunks_empty();
    coordinates coord1;
    coordinates coord2;
    for (int i=0; i<SPACE_DIMENSION; i++) {
        coord1[i] = i+1;
        coord2[i] = 2*i+5;
    }
    chunks_write_data(&chunks, coord1, block1);
    CU_ASSERT(block_equal(block1, chunks_select_data(chunks, coord1)))
    CU_ASSERT_FALSE(block_equal(block2, chunks_select_data(chunks, coord1)))
    struct block* block3 = chunks_select_data(chunks, coord2);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // According to the debugger, at this point block2 is 0x605600 and block3 is 0x0
    CU_ASSERT_FALSE(block_equal(block2, block3))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Paste the implementation of test_chunks_write, too.

Comment: And how are `block2` and `block3` initialised? Are they explicitly set?

Comment: @DanielFischer I just added the full implementation

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't see `block3` anywhere except in the `block_equal` call. What's up with that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I involuntarily removed the line when adding the comment. Fixed.

Comment: You're incredibly fast fixing these things, I have to applaud you for that :)

Comment: Is it possible that `chunks_select_data` has a code path that doesn't explicitly return a valid pointer?

Comment: `chunks_select_data` returns a void*. (Sorry if this is not the answer you expected, I am not sure about what you mean by "code path".)

Comment: I mean that maybe in one condition, you've forgotten a `return some_pointer;` or return a pointer that isn't properly initialised. Not very likely, but it's the only idea I get from looking at the code.

Comment: When running through the debugger, everything happens exactly as I wish (after hours of debugging, of course), except this valgrind error.

Comment: Just for clarity, I would replace `^` by `!=` and `&` by `&&`. Semantically, bit operations don't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the value is not initialized, so this can point to anything; I don't know what the debugger does tell me it's 0x0. I will write my tests differently (testing the address instead, for example).